# scrapyd Exception Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapyd

When I execute

```
curl http://localhost:6800/schedule.json -d project=default -d spider=spider1
```

I go to scrapyd console and I see the Exception:

```
[-] Unhandled Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/scrapyV1/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 150, in maybeDeferred
    result = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/home/scrapyV1/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1274, in unwindGenerator
    return _inlineCallbacks(None, gen, Deferred())
  File "/home/scrapyV1/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1128, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = g.send(result)
  File "/home/scrapyV1/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapyd/poller.py", line 23, in poll
    msg = yield maybeDeferred(q.pop)
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "/home/scrapyV1/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 150, in maybeDeferred
    result = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/home/scrapyV1/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapyd/spiderqueue.py", line 21, in pop
    return self.q.pop()
  File "/home/scrapyV1/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapyd/sqlite.py", line 119, in pop
    return self.decode(msg)
  File "/home/scrapyV1/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapyd/sqlite.py", line 170, in decode
    return json.loads(text)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 366, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
exceptions.ValueError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)nter code here
```

After that I can't run next Spider, I get

```
{"status": "error", "message": "No JSON object could be decoded", "node_name": "spider-test2"}
```

How to determine what that error is related to?

Comment: Presumably the problem is in sqlite3 version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in sqlite3 installed in my Centos6.5.
Decision:
need to add

```
self.conn.text_factory = bytes
```

to SqliteDict and SqlitePriorityQueue classes after connect creation in a `scrapyd/sqlite.py b/scrapyd/sqlite.py`